# How to detect ThinkPad T530 volume up and down keys?

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, volume-control, remapping

I'm using my Logitech M510 mouse's scroll buttons (left & right) to change the volume level. Using xbindkeys I can set them with command like this:

```
amixer -c 0 set Master playback 2dB+ unmute
```

But these amixer commands doesn't show the volume popup and they also doesn't maximize the volume to it's maximum. This happens because in sound setting I saw that the sign for 100% is not at the end of the slider but around the 80.

So, how can I detect the buttons for volume up and down from the keyboard. Then with xbindkeys I will bind my mouse buttons to work like them.

`xev` doesn't show anything when pressing the buttons from the keyboard. Instead of this they are working fine with Linux, just not detected by `xev` and I can't get the key number for using in xbindkeys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons are `XF86AudioRaiseVolume` and `XF86AudioLowerVolume`.

They are not detected by `xev`, don't know why. But after using these values it worked.

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_T530#keybinding